# Can't access vagrant folder on vagrant machine (Stale file handle)

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm currently stuck on a problem for 2 days already.
I've recently updated my mac OS to OS Catalina (I know I should have waited) and I cant access the `/vagrant` folder on the vagrant machine.

My nfs configuration looks like this:

```
project_config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc', 'nolock', 'actimeo=2']
```

And this is the output when I try to execute an `ls` in vagrant ssh:

```
vagrant@project:/vagrant$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Stale file handle
```

There is also running a Docker container inside my vagrant and the installation looks like this (`Vagrantfile`):

```
project_config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
  d.build_image "/vagrant/docker/reverse-proxy", args: "-t='reverse-proxy'"
  d.run "reverse-proxy", args: "-v '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 8080:8080"
end
```

Error I get after executing a `vagrant up`:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

docker build -t='reverse-proxy' /vagrant/docker/reverse-proxy

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

unable to prepare context: path "/vagrant/docker/reverse-proxy" not found
```

I think that this error is related to the vagrant folder. Like access or something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Fix:**

I finally managed to fix it!

The problem was that my project was located in the **Documents** folder of my Mac `/Users/USERNAME/Documents/project` but this doesn't work anymore so I have moved the project to a new folder called **Projects** in my home directory. `/Users/USERNAME/Projects/project`.

I hope I can help someone with this.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem here too, nfs shares under ~/Documents appeared to mount fine, then where unusable! Thanks!

Comment: @Ecuador I'm glad this was helpful!

Comment: This has fixed my issue as well! Thanks for posting the fix.

Comment: same here, is there any explanation why does not work under Documents?

Comment: @Erfan I think it has something to do with the new write permissions to specific folders in the new Catalina OS.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps your error is caused by configuring the guest to have a synced folder at the `/vagrant` directory. This overwrites the entire folder with the contents of your synced folder.

My personal set-up is as follows:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./code", "/home/vagrant/code"
```

This way, you create a new directory in your root directory without overwriting the key files in the `/vagrant` directory.

Hope this helps, best regards.

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the error: `mount: /vagrant: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'.`

Comment: This issue happens when the vagrant box does not have VirtualBox Guest Additions installed. Here is a link to the documentation: [link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html#virtualbox-guest-additions)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same issue - instead of moving your whole project like in the accepted answer you can also give /sbin/nsfd full disk access:

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10961#issuecomment-541070382

Then you can still have your projects in Documents